# Log4net not able to log into database after deployed on production

Tags: c#, amazon-rds, log4net

The issue I am facing:

Log4net is working absolutely fine when tested locally, errors are logged into the database but after the deployment, no errors are logged in the database table for logging.
Amazon RDS is used to connect to the database.

I have tried almost all the possible solutions suggested on the internet but nothing helped.

- Checked the grants to the table, there is no grant or permission issue.
- Changed the value of buffersize =1, didn't help
- Added `<trust level="Full" />`, didn't helped

The same log4net file is working fine on other environments (even after deployment) the difference is that we are not using Amazon service as a host but normal IIS(window server 2012R2) on other environments.
The other difference is for a long time application used the oracle database as backend but now recently the application is redeployed on Amazon, so the other difference is now the database is not exactly 'oracle' it is Amazon oracle RDS.

Is there any specific permission that I need to give on amazon or is there any extra configuration for log4net?
When locally tested worked fine but no log into the database after deployment.

Log4net File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="Oracle" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionString name="DBConnectionString_Logging" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc.amazonaws.com)(PORT=xxxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ServiceName)));User Id= ABC;Password=abc;" />
    <connectionType value="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.2.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logging (ID,Timestamp,Log_Level,Source,Message,Application,Stacktrace) VALUES (LOGGING_SEQ.nextval,:log_date, :log_level, :logger, :message, 2, :exception)" />
    <bufferSize value="10" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.Core.TimeEvaluator">
      <interval value="60"/>
    </evaluator>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="1000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value=":exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%exception" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Oracle" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Global.asax file

```
private void ConfigureLogging() 
    {
                FileInfo configFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config"));
                XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFile);
    }
```

Comment: Is the Oracle database accessible from the EC2 machine?

Comment: Hi Chetan, yes oracle database is accessible from the EC2 machine

Comment: Are you calling `ConfigureLogging` method in app_start?

Comment: yes, I have called ConfigureLogging in application_start

Answer (score 0):

I got it, the issue was because of the oracle.DataAccess dll version, the dll that was used in the project was version 4.11 and the version specified in the log4net is version 2.102.2.20.
Thanks